# Fetch request doesn't return JSON from an endpoint

Tags: javascript, fetch, hapi.js

I'm trying to get a JSON data from an endpoint located in route `/users` at the same domain but somehow I always get error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

When I take a look at location of the error I'm getting the source of the index page (same page where script is ran).

This is the route (Hapi.js):

```
allUsers: {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/users',
    options: AuthHelper.required,
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        let users = [];
        let error = false;

        await User.find({})
        .lean().then(result => {
            if (result && result.length) users = db.filterResult(result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            error = true;
            console.log(err);
        });

        if (error) {
            return { message: 'There is an error.' };
        } else {
            return { users: users };
        }
    }
}
```

This is the client side code:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/users').then((response) => response.json()).then((json) => console.log(json));
```

When I visit the URL in a browser directly, I get the results.

[image]

Comment: when in the browser do you see a well-formatted json output?

Comment: When I visit the URL directly.

Comment: ok and what outputs `console.log(result)`?

Comment: You mean `console.log(json)` or maybe `console.log(response)` ? I get the pending `Promise` as a result and the error message I wrote.

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and see waht response body looks like there. That error often means html is being returned ... first character would be`<` of `<!doctype>`

Comment: Double check the URL the request is actually being sent to. That error appears when you treat an HTML page (e.g. a 404 page) as JSON. And this is usually due to errors in the URL path, such as typos.

Comment: Please do the following: 1) open a shell / Terminal and type `curl http://localhost:3000/users`, and attach here the output. Let's check the response headers then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized where the problem is thanks to charlieftl. I opened up **Network** tab and followed where request was going - it was a login page. There were no credentials sent with request (and as it can be seen from the code, route is protected) so response always returned source of index page because I was redirected back.

I just had to add `same-origin` property to a `credentials` option.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/users', { credentials: 'same-origin' }).then((response) => response.json()).then((json) => console.log(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you should use the `reply` interface method, so that hapi will automatically convert it into valid JSON:

```
 allUsers: {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/users',
    options: AuthHelper.required,
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        let users = [];
        let error = false;

        await User.find({})
        .lean().then(result => {
            if (result && result.length) users = db.filterResult(result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            error = true;
            console.log(err);
        });

        if (error) {
            return { message: 'There is an error.' };
        } else {
            reply( { users: users } );
        }
    }
}
```